# Get Keyboard text value Mono for Android

Tags: android, keyboard, xamarin.android

How can I get keyboard text value when keyboard created with

```
InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(yourActivity.this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the key listener for the view which needs the text value

```
setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() { //Make the view listen for key events
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//Your code
            return true;
        }            
    });
```